# Laptop WiFi seemingly hardblocked

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 18.04, hp

My laptop's WiFi card doesn't seem to work:

```
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 59)
```

I have tried installing the appropriate drivers from Intel's official [website](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html).

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.1

rfkill returns:

```
ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
0 bluetooth hci0   unblocked unblocked
1 wlan      phy0   unblocked   blocked
```

I have also turned off secure boot. My WiFi works perfectly fine in Windows 10, however, it does not work at all in Ubuntu. This is a fresh install of Ubuntu so I am not opposed to reinstalling though I have already tried that once. If it's at all related, I have `acpi=off` set as a boot flag, otherwise my laptop freezes up after a minute of use. My laptop is an [HP Pavilion 15t](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B076YG518T).

Also, [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tdtpXKk9fm/) is the output of details about my wireless card provided by the all-in-one script.

If there is anymore information I can provide, don't hesitate to ask.

Edit: I have tried using a USB WiFi dongle that works with a Raspberry Pi and it does not work. It even shows as unblocked in the `rfkill` but still does not work.

Edit 2: Here is the output of `iwconfig`

```
wlx000f6006f65a  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
      Retry short  long limit:2   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.

eno1      no wireless extensions.
```

A quick note, 'wlx000f6006f65a' is my USB WiFi dongle and 'wlo1' is my Intel WiFi card

Edit 3: During the initial installation of Ubuntu, when prompted to select my WiFi network, `Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 59)` was listed as a choice.

Edit 4: I have tried enabling networking in Recovery Mode, however it hangs after I hit yes to confirm remounting filesystem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I finally managed to fix the problem. For some background info, my laptop has integrated graphics as well as a GTX 1050 Ti. In an attempt to fix another issue, I installed the Nvidia proprietary drivers for my graphics card. As part of this process, I had to set a MOK password and enable MOK upon reboot. I also deleted `acpi=off` from my boot flags. I believe deleting that boot flag fixed my issue, but in the case that it was because I enabled MOK, I am providing you all of that information.

Answer (score 0):

Had also issues with Wifi on two laptops after installing 18.04
Fix: Replace default network manager with alternative.
Here is one link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WICD

Comment: Tried that but upon restarting I was not able to access my settings panel. In addition to that, my WiFi still did not work so I reverted the change back to the original.

Answer (score 0):

Try unplugging your computer from the power outlet, shutting it down and letting it sit for a few minutes. Then start it up (keeping it unplugged) and see what happens.

Comment: It's a laptop. I've tried removing the battery for a few minutes while it's unplugged, but that didn't work.